# Implementing http retries with refresh token flow

Tags: java, rest, recursion, oauth-2.0, httpclient

I have a java command line application that authenticates with an external service using the OAuth 2.0 device flow. It makes various REST calls to this service, but sometimes the Access Token expires. When it expires I get a 401 response code. I’ve handled this response code by using the refresh token flow to get a new Access Token, then I recursively call the same function again to perform the action with the new token.

This is working for me and I’ve implemented retry limits, but it feels wrong.  I’m not sure how I can implement this as a common function. I’ve been copying and pasting the same logic all over my code.  I’ve been trying to search for alternative approaches, but haven’t found anything yet. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

According to OAuth2 RFC https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749 it seems you're using Client Credentials flow which is not actually required to have a refresh token since an application can easily request any number of tokens.

So I would recommend to just get a new access token once an existing expires.

Only once you have a user involved (Authorization Code, Implicit or Password flows) it starts making sense to manage refresh tokens as well to avoid bothering a user.